# How to add data to PDF from sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SharePoint list and from few of the fields want to fetch data and add it to PDF which is editable.

**E.g**: Want to add physical address to policy template

I tried power automate to build new PDF from SharePoint but didn't get solutions for template which is already there.

Appreciate your help!! Thanks

Mangesh Malvankar

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this sample solution already does what you need
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-command-print

Comment: No this is not what I want, thanks